# jQuery - write new plugin - this.foreach doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently writing a little JS something, and as it might get re-used in my company I want to do it right and write is as a jQuery plugin (jQuery is definitely needed for ease, so I have decided upon relying on it).

Now, I am a relatively experienced developer regarding jQuery, but I have a problem that is probably incredibly simple to solve and still I do not know where I am going wrong.

I included the jQuery file like normal from the CDN, then my plugin file and last of all the js file that I use to test the plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tsnowglobe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Then I try to define the plugin in the `jquery.tsnowglobe.js` file.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.snowglobe = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            console.log("Test!");
        };  
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This is obviously only to test wether everything is working or not.

Well, the problem is: I don't get any output when I use my plugin.
I have defined a canvas in the HTML part (I also tried multiple, didn't work):

```
<canvas id="snowglobe"></canvas>
```

And then I consecutively try to use the `snowglobe`-function on it in the `main.js`-file (which is loaded last):

```
$("canvas").snowglobe();
```

Well, the problem is, I get absolutely no output. Now, I think I might have identified the problem: inside my function definition, `this` is not an array. What really irritates me that all tutorials use the same code as a start, so as far as I see it should be working, and even if I wrap this in an array I cannot access any DOM-element-properties inside the loop, as `this` in that case does not refer to any DOM element itself.

Thanks in advance for helping me! I am really not sure what I could do to solve this.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Make sure to look at your console. (You didn't close the `each` properly).

Comment: You were missing a `)` closing the `.each()` loop - it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/69uLrbd6/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the code, as it has quite a bit more stuff already in it (class definitions and such). There were no errors.

That said, I tried just copying your code, and it suddenly started working, even though it was exactly the same. Very strange. Thanks, guys!